# Mixed plot with histogram and superimposed line plot in same figure

Tags: r, plot

I know there are strong opinions about mixing plot types in the same figures, especially if there are two y axes involved. However, this is a situation in which I have no alternative - I need to create a figure using R that follows a standard format - a histogram on one axis (case counts), and a superimposed line graph showing an unrelated rate on an independent axis.

The best I have been able to do is stacked ggplot2 facets, but this is not as easy to interpret for the purposes of this analysis as the combined figure. The people reviewing this output will need it in the format they are used to.

I'm attaching an example below. 
[image: figure1]

Any ideas?

For etiquette purposes, sample data below:

```
y1<-sample(0:1000,20,rep=TRUE)
y2<-sample(0:100,20,rep=TRUE)
x<-1981:2000
```

Comment: you need to include some sample data

Comment: A bit complicated, but take a look at this for dual y axis plots: https://rpubs.com/kohske/dual_axis_in_ggplot2

Comment: Thanks, @Chani. That's a good start. I'll try messing with that approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel your pain - have had to recreate plots before.  even did it in SAS once

if it's a once off, I'm be tempted to go old-school.  something like this:

```
# Generate some data
someData <- data.frame(Year = 1987:2009,
  mCases = rpois(23, 3),
  pVac = sample(55:80, 23, T))

par(mar = c(5, 5, 5, 5))
with(someData, {

  # Generate the barplot
  BP <- barplot(mCases, ylim = c(0, 18), names = Year, 
    yaxt = "n", xlab = "", ylab = "Measles cases in Thousands")
  axis(side = 2, at = 2*1:9, las = 1)
  box()

  # Add the % Vaccinated
  par(new = T)
  plot(BP, pVac, type = "l", ylim = c(0, 100), axes = F, ylab = "", xlab = "")
  axis(side = 4, las = 1)
  nudge <- ifelse(pVac > median(pVac), 2, -2)
  text(BP, pVac + nudge, pVac)
  mtext(side = 4, "% Vaccinated", line = 3)
  par(new = F)
})
```

Comment: have not added the arrows at the top of the plot - if they are data driven you could include those too with `?arrows` and `?text`

Comment: that was quick and humbling - thanks much for your very complete answer. This is very helpful. Would be nice to know if it's possible using fancier packages like ggplot2 or lattice, but this will fit the bill extremely well.

Comment: multiple axes isn't straightforward in lattice or ggplot, but is doable (as per the link Chani posted)

Answer (score 1):

Try `library(plotrix)`

```
library(plotrix)

## Create sample data
y2<-sample(0:80,20,rep=TRUE)
x2<-sort(sample(1980:2010,20,rep=F))
y1<-sample(0:18,20,rep=TRUE)
x1<-sort(sample(1980:2010,20,rep=F))
x<-1980:2010

twoord.plot(x1,y1,x2,y2,
            lylim=c(0,18),rylim=c(0,100),type=c("bar","l"),
            ylab="Measles Cases in thousands",rylab="% Vaccinated",
            lytickpos=seq(0,18,by=2),rytickpos=seq(0,100,by=10),ylab.at=9,rylab.at=50,
            lcol=3,rcol=4)
```

[image]

Comment: That's a nice package I didn't know about - thanks so much @Chani. Both of these are exactly what I was looking for. Appreciate the help.